# About first Chern class and Poincaré duality in case of an ample divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, chern-classes, ample-bundles

Led $D$ be a very ample divisor in $X$ projective variety.

I can't understand why the first Chern class $c_1(\mathscr{O}_X(D))$ equals the Poincaré dual of $D$, $\mathscr{P}(D)$

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, but not for this site.  The best place for this question is math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also if you post the question on Math stackexchange, you should state what definition of Chern class you are using.

Comment: Since this is a graduate level question, it *does seem* appropriate
here. In a nutshell, since $D$ is very ample, you can reduce the
problem to $X=\mathbb{P}^n$. Since $H^2(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ in this case,
$D$ and $c_1(O(1))$ are multiples of each other. By restricting to a line, you can check the factor is $1$. I may flesh this out later,
if I have time.

Comment: We have the following short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \Omega ^1_X\rightarrow \Omega ^1_X(\log D)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D\rightarrow 0$ and since for the total Chern class we have from pervious short exact sequence $\ c(\Omega ^1_X(\log D))=c(\Omega ^1_X).c(\mathcal{O}_D)$ and since $c(\mathcal{O}_D)=(1-[D])^{-1}$ hence $c_p(\Omega ^1_X(\log D))=c_p(\Omega ^1_X)+c_{p-1}(\Omega ^1_X).[D]+\ldots +[D]^p$ hence $c_1(\Omega_X^1(\log D))= c_1(\Omega_X^1)+[D]$